# Decorate a row or field in Yii CGridView if database shows a certain value

Tags: php, yii

I was having problems trying to get CSS to decorate the appropriate field in a Grid View using Yii's CGridView or TbGridView (which extends CGridView).

The last time I posted this question (which was unanswered for a few weeks at the time) I was downvoted to hell and also had the post closed.

Comment: Alright that you're contributing but 1. You didn't even give time for others to answer (again) & 2. Many people see this as ["rep farming"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126987/186879).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  That's a joke right? What sick-twisted-freak gets off on fake Internet points?  Regardless, I hope the solution shows up in future search engines to assist other people.

Comment: Well, close/downvoters are a little eccentric at times. That's what I can say from experience. And on-topic, I'm starting with Yii and IMO their documentation isn't nearly as good as other older frameworks' documentation such as CodeIgniter (might be my slightly biased view), so all info we can have on these new frameworks will be of use.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I agree with Yii's documentation lacking and appreciate the words of experience.  I felt the same way about Yii and found it to be quite a mountain to climb.  Similar to a mountain though, you don't know how high you are until you look down.  It does accelerate future developments.  CakePHP, CodeIgniter, and Symfony have better docs.  Yii is getting there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns[]=array(
/* 'class'=>'CDataColumn', */ /* it's the default */
'header'=>'Challenge',
'type'=>'raw',
'value'=>'($data->player->underChallenge!=1)
    ? CHtml::link("ChalengePlayer", array("player/view", "id"=>$data->player->id))
    : "Under Challenge"',
);
```

[Yii forum link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17485-cgridview-conditional-clinkcolumns/)